# ReferenceError: Property 'document' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, react-leaflet

When adding the libraries to my code i get the error: "ReferenceError: Property 'document' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes"

I have not added anything else does someone now what the issue is and how to resolve te problem, i am using react-native-expo

Answer (score 1):

Check your installed packages. Some packages works for web. Uninstall them. Don't forget you are developing in react-native.

Comment: Also I saw you are using react-leaflet. That package can cause the problem because it can't be used in react-native